# Java library for 3D matrix operations

Tags: java, matrix, 3d

I'm searching for a library able to perform operations (such as inverse,transpose,addition,subtraction, etc.) on 3D matrices.

So far, I have tried Apache Commons Math and Colt libraries, but none of them seems to be good in dealing with 3D matrices...

Any suggestions?...

Answer (score 1):

There's a "standard" Java library for 3D vector and matrix operations - `javax.vecmath` from [Java 3D](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you like R, [JRI](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-r-integration-jri-demand) could be a good solution.

Also, if you have a lot of data and like R, try [RHIPE](http://www.datadr.org/).

Comment: I can't find 3D matrices in EJML...
In which class are they?

Comment: A colleague told me they're there, but I can't find them either. Absent my own verification, I amended my answer. Sorry for the mixup.

Comment: Also, EJML has a page with performance metrics, which is notable only in that it stands to reason the creator chose the leading libraries in the space to test against. Perhaps one of those may suit you: https://code.google.com/p/java-matrix-benchmark/

Answer (score 0):

[JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) has worked well for me.  I've used it for concatenating and inverting 4x4 matrices, among other functions.  Works well, easy to learn API, does everything I need it to.